# Location updates issue for iOS 7

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, location

I'm developing an iOS map application, so it's essential to receive location data consistently. 
What is happening now is that the system allows the to app load the map and that's it!

The location getting instruction seems to freeze, even the network traffic indicator at the top bar disappears. Simply when I go to Settings->Privacy->Location Updates, switch off location updates for my app and then switch it back on. The map loads the current location.

What could be the possible causes to this?, please advice.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
[_mapView setUserTrackingMode:MKUserTrackingModeFollow animated:YES];
```

This will smoothly follow the users current location. If you drag the map it will even set the tracking mode back to MKUserTrackingModeNone which is usually the behaviour you want.

Comment: I'm using the iOS ArcGIS SDK, all MK instructions are not supported.

Comment: I dont have much knowledge on that SDK. Have a look at below tutorial. Guess that may help you.

Comment: I already have their samples, and I don't really have trouble getting the location data in concept. This is mostly a non-code related issue unless someone could explain is it possible to add an instantly effective Refresh Location feature maybe?